# Is it possible to create an Angular application without bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular-material, angular6

Is it possible to create an Angular application with complete material design and removing bootstrap ? 
What is the advantage and disadvantage ?

Answer (score 2):

Some feature aren’t included in Angular Material like Carousel, typical navbar (they use toolbar), affix.
Datepicker/Datetimepicker is awesome, forms are killing too good, they are do lot of work in buttons, icon buttons.
If your are focusing on web + mobile application you must choose Angular Material.

But if your want to make a only web app so you will go with Bootstrap 4  There are lot of things and very fast support in this as compare to Material.